# Conexão do PHP em banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, amazon-aws, conexão

Estou usando localhost e tentando fazer uma conexão do PHP em um banco de dados existente (MySQL/AWS), consigo conectar pelo Workbench, porém nada no PHP, criei uma pasta e adicionei 2 arquivos > conexao.php e index.php, após, subi a pasta localhost pelo CMD. [erro que retorna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJX3q.jpg)
Estou usando VSCODE.

```
    /*pasta conexao.php/ <?php
    
    $host= "hostname";
    $user= "user";
    $pass= "pass";
    $dbname= "dbname";
    
    try {
        $conn =  new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        echo "conexão realizada";
        } catch (PDOException $err) {
            echo "erro de conexão" . $err->getMessage();
    }
/*pasta index.php/
<?php
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Pesquisa</h2>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Acontece esse erro pq é necessário ter o drive mysql para PDO

Instale a extensão "pdo_mysql"